# where is the root of the Xcode app project directory located?

Tags: xcode

I'm following a app tutorial and it says:

"Next, create an empty file in the root of the Xcode app project directory and call the file Podfile. Open it with your favorite text editor and paste the following line in it:"

I'm confused exactly where this is? is it inside my Xcode program? or is it some folder inside my Xcode folder in finder?

Comment: Usually, Podfile are located in the same folder (in Finder) as .xcodeproj file or as .xcworkspace file, if workspace is used.

Comment: Ironically, I'm following the same tutorial and was wondering the same thing.

Comment: I'll try to add the pod file to the same folder as the .xcodeproj file is, and see if it works. I won't be able to figure it out before I totally done with the guide probably. But I will comeback and update if it worked.

Comment: How do you add or even create the pod file?

Comment: i don't know, I can't get it to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

Open Terminal, navigate to the directory that has your project. Type it like this:

`cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/yourProject`

I saved mine on my desktop so it was simple.

Then type: `pod init`

This creates the pod file.

Then type:

`open -a Xcode Podfile`

This will open the file so that you can edit it.

Comment: You are a life saver if this works!! However, I can't figure out my path ever though I have it on my desktop as well. 

@lukeslvi

Comment: To break it down: Type this: `cd ~/Desktop` and then type: `ls` to list everything on your desktop. That's just to check that it's there. Then type: `cd ~/Desktop/Paws` (your Xcode folder name). It should then say: `lukas-macbook-pro:Paws luka$` (your name + computer name obviously). Le the know if this helps. PS, the pods are out of date so I'm also looking for the newest pod versions. Let me know if you got it.

Comment: I got it to work, seriously thanks so much. Saved my day!
Now that I opened the pod file it says: 

    `# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '8.0'
    # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
    # use_frameworks!

    target 'Paws' do 

    end

    target 'PawsTests' do

    end
`

Comment: Would you remove all that, and write in "pod ‘Parse’, ‘~> 1.7.1’
pod ‘ParseUI’, ‘~> 1.1.3’" 

?

Comment: I did not know they are outdate, but so far it all worked after I typed "install pods"

Comment: @lukeslvi I think it should work with those pods, because I just completed the whole step which said if your app runs now, you have correctly said everything up. And my app is running with no errors.

Comment: problem is, after instilling the pods you should get a message that says `Use Paws.xcworkspace`. This is the project that you have to use after installing cocoa pods. I'm not getting that new project nor that message.

Comment: I'm just going to install the newest version and continue. It's the same thing.  You can download the latest starter project here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/releases or use this link: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Parse. PS, I'd really recommend updating the question to reflect installing parse on cocoa-pods to help others in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94546/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-frederic).

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in Terminal.
Once in Terminal:

1. type `cd` (there is a space after cd)
2. drag your project to the Terminal window and press return. It points Terminal to your project.
3. type `touch .Podfile`, which will create an empty file in your project
4. type `open -a TextEdit .Podfile`, which will open the .Podfile file in TextEdit
5. paste your code in it and then save.
6. you can check that your Podfile has been created by typing `ls -a` in Terminal, which will show you all files and folders in your project

This should work.